# Dialogflow, how to reuse Intent within another Intent

Tags: dialogflow-es

I'm building a Dialogflow app that depends on user provided location a lot. I found a pre-built agent called "Maps" that shows how to train the agent to identify locations from user's statement. However, I would like to keep this location resolution logic somewhat separate and use it part of another Intent instead of cluttering everything in the same Intent.

Is it possible to re-use Intent within another Intent?
Or
Is there a different design pattern?

Answer (score 0):

An agent is made up of multiple intents.  You can add more intents to your maps agent.

Alternatively, a common practice is to have multiple agents but build an abstraction layer middle between users and the agents.  This abstraction layer can coordinate sharing context between the multiple agents.  The catch is that this means you can’t use the dialogflow connectors that make it super easy to publish your agent for Google Assistant, Facebook Messenger, Slack, Twilio, etc.  You’ll need to do your own work to connect those to your agent abstraction layer.

Answer (score 0):

You can try a workaround using contexts.

- Have all the intents as top-level intents without any fallback or follow-up intents.
- Use context in the code for fallback or follow-up intents to identify the action/intent and perform tasks.

---

```
|--- Default Welcome
|
|--- Default Fallback (single fallback for all, use context to identify intent you want to serve)
|
|--- Follow-up YES (serve YES follow-up for all using context)
|
|--- Follow-up NO (serve NO follow-up for all using context)
|
|--- Intent A (out context A)
|
|--- Intent B (out context B)
|
..
..
|
|--- Other Intents
```